# How to determine if collection contains items of specific type?

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

everyone, I have a question,
How to determine if a collection contains items of specific type?
For example I have ItemCollection of an ItemControl

```
var items = comboBox.Items;
```

I need to know what type of item in the Items collection that is my question

for example I need to determine if
Items is collection of items type of string
or DependencyObject or other type.

Help me please resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, where exactly does your implementation fail?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your question. What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: See updates in the question and question title

Comment: I join @Heinzi in the quest to understand your problem. Items[i].GetType() will return the type of the item in position [i], and you can compare that to typeof(string) or typeof(DependencyObject)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Type> types = (from item in comboBox.Items select item.GetType()).Distinct();
```

This yields a list of all the types that appear in your combo box items.

If you just want to test whether one specific type appears in your list, you can do the following:

```
bool containsStrings = comboBox.Items.OfType<string>.Any()
bool containsDependencyObjects = comboBox.Items.OfType<DependencyObject>.Any()
```

Answer (score 4):

easy with Linq:

```
var itemsOfTypeString = comboBox.Items.OfType<string>();
var itemsOfTypeDependencyObject = comboBox.Items.OfType<DependencyObject>();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        foreach (object item in comboBox.Items)
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {
                //DoYourStuff
            }
        }
```